# What is the probability distribution of X, if X is the number of times the letter 'e' appears from the set {beware, the, jabberwock, my, son}

Tags: probability-distributions, binary

**A string of letter is chose uniformly at random from the set**

**{beware, the, jabberwock, my, son}**

**Let *X* be the number of times the letter 'e' appears in the string. Give the probability distribution of *X*.**

This is how I attempted it:

let 1 represent e and 0 represent not e

X= {010001, 001, 0000100000, 00, 000}

Is this correct?

Comment: X can take three values: 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: does that mean that you have to pick an element from the set?

Comment: When you say a string is chosen "uniformly at random"  do you mean it has to be one of those $5$ words or can it be any subset (possibly empty) of the $24$ characters? (assuming I counted correctly).

Comment: Hint: the probability of each string (actually, word) is 1/5. Each string is associated with a number (number of "e"s). Each outcome is trivially disjoint. Can you continue from there?

Comment: @lulu I am not really sure, I took this question directly out of my assignment questions. It is not specified there.

Comment: Well...path of least resistance is to assume that it just means "choose one of the following five words, each with probability $\frac 15$".

Comment: @Bey Ok so in this case is this correct X= {2, 1, 1, 0, 0} ?

Comment: Yep! Now, attach probabilities to each outcome, noting that each word represents a unique outcome. E.g. choosing "the" and "my" are mutually exclusive, since they are elementary events/outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct. First, here $X$ is a number (random), not a set.

When you're asked "give the probability distribution of $X$", your answer needs to be

$P(X=a) = ?$, $P(X=b) = ?$, etc.

So, what's the probability that $X=0$? that $X=1$ and $X=2$? Is there another value that $X$ can take ?

Comment: Does this mean P(x=beware) = 2/24 , P(X= the) =1/24?

Comment: So what is the number associated with e? is it 1?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing some comments I believe this would be my answer

*P(X= Beware)* = 2/5

*P(X= the)* = 1/5

*P(X = jabberwork)* = 1/5

*P(X= my)* = 0

*P(X= son)* = 0

Feel free to state whether this is right or wrong

Comment: No, not correct. X is a number (the number of "e"s). The probability that you choose each word is 1/5, but some words have the same number of e's, so, for example, $P(X=0)=2/5$ based on your calculation in the comments.

Comment: @Bey Can you show me the answer? I don't mean to cheat (it's not going to be maarked anyway), but I think I will understand it better if I can see how it's done.

Comment: wait I think I got it. How about this P(X=0) = 2/5, P(X=1) = 2/5 and P(X=2) = 1/5. If we total the probabilities we get 1 which make sense

Comment: (+1) Yep. That's correct. The basic approach for calculating the distribution of a discrete random variable is to calculate its value at each point in the *sample space*, then collect similar values (if any) and add up the probability of the sample points that led to each of those outcomes.